# Azure tables: Retrieve entire table

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I know how to get some table entities from an Azure table like this:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(...);
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("table");
TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve(...);
TableResult retrievedResult = table.Execute(retrieveOperation);
```

or

```
TableQuery<MyEntity> query = new TableQuery<MyEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(...);
```

but I was wondering: is there a nice way to retrieve an entire table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `TableQuery` to get the entire table.

```
var list = new List<MyEntity>();
var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("table");
var tableQuery = new TableQuery<UserEntity>();
TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
do
{
    var query = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(
        tableQuery, continuationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    list.AddRange(query.Results);
    continuationToken = query.ContinuationToken;
} while (continuationToken != null);
```